# <td>TITLE STRING</td> value refers to if else condition

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In MVC, we can use `x == y ? x : y` as if else condition.
How can I use this condition inside the ?
In order to return what should be the text title of my page?

i have cope-up a code like this but returns error.

```
<td class="userfrom-cell-midasi" colspan="11" ><% Model.ChargeREFCode == "1" ? "ユーザー追加登録　入力フォーム : "SV追加登録　入力フォーム" %></td>
```

can someone help me with this? thanks in advance,

Comment: Error in Code: Expected `;`, And if put a semicolon on my code. then it will return, `Only Assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expresstions can be used as a statement`. How to fix this sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Soviut's answer which explains incorrect string formatting, to use ternary operator in view page you must assign it to a variable like this:

```
<% 
    var contentString = Model.ChargeREFCode == "1" ? "ユーザー追加登録　入力フォーム" : "SV追加登録　入力フォーム"; 
    // do something with the variable
%>
```

And you can output the string to view page like this:

```
<td class="userfrom-cell-midasi" colspan="11" ><%= contentString %></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

The shorthand if statement is known as a ternary conditional operator.

You're first string is formatted incorrectly. You can tell this because it isn't highlighting correctly in the code snippet. You need to close it with double quotes.

```
<% Model.ChargeREFCode == "1" ? "ユーザー追加登録　入力フォーム" : "SV追加登録　入力フォーム" %>
                                                            ^
```

I've highlighted the location of the missing quote with a `^` character.

Comment: Error in Code: Expected `;`, And if put a semicolon on my code. then it will return, `Only Assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expresstions can be used as a statement`. How to fix this sir?